# Javascript: Calling a function inside another function

Tags: javascript

First function contains the input and the second has if/else logic. I'm calling second function inside first but the if/else statements are seems to not working.

```js
var choice = function(){

    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
     computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
     computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
     computerChoice = "scissors";
    } console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
    compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
};

var compare = function(choice1, choice2){

    if(choice1 === choice2){
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } 
    else if(choice1 === "rock"){
        if(choice2 === "scissors"){
            return "rock wins";
        } 
        else{
            return "paper wins";
        }    
    } 
    else if(choice1 === "paper"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "paper wins";
        } else{
            return "scissors wins";
        }  
    } 
    else if(choice1 === "scissors"){
        if(choice2 === "rock"){
            return "rock wins";
        } else{
            return "scissors wins";
        }  
    } 
    else{
        return "invalid input";
    }   
};

choice();
```

Comment: Your `compare()` function returns a string that you don't use in any way. If you want the user to see the result try `alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well.

```
compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

**returns** an appropriate result.

However, you did not display it. So display it with `alert()`, etc.:

```
alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```